# Ask for architecture evaluation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

As a novice in software architecture, i believe it would be a great source of knowledge feedback from the community in form of "evaluation". I was thinking in something like:

- describe the "problem"
- attach purposed design (as UML or something like that...)
- and a pretty "pls give me your feedback"

And in return I am expecting answers like:

- Oh you should make class here implement that interface also,
- This will not work with EF because of x,y,z
- This is a good design, but isn't it a bit over the top for the problem in question?
- etc...

But first i though about swinging by here and ask if that is a good idea... or this is just not the place for this kind of question?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Reviewing a piece of code / software / website isn't what a q and a site is for. There is no review that could be marked as Correct.

Comment: @JonW When more than one person provide, different but correct answers to a given question? I, choose the best/more explained/thoughtful/detailed one, what you do?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin thank you! pls post your comment as answer so i can accept it!

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: Code Review is for review of *source code*, according to its intro: "Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer **code reviews**." It's not for discussion or review questions about architecture in general. Please review the site guidelines before referring users to the site.

Comment: @KenWhite - I assumed that since they were talking about class implementation that there would be some code included.  I thought they were going for a "barebones" structure type thing that they wanted reviewed before they finished writing out all the methods/behaviors/whatever.  I have read the guidelines over there... and it does say "code" and "review" in the URL.  I can only assume that's what it's for...?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: The post here says "describe the problem, attach purposed design (as UML or something like that...), and ask for feedback". There's no mention of code to review. CR is for posting actual, working code for peer review. Programmers would probably be more appropriate, although I haven't checked the guidelines there to see if this specific type of question is a fit there. I doubt that "give me feedback" is going to be a fit anywhere here, however; SE in general is for *specific questions* that can be clearly answered.

Comment: I just thought they were adding that, too... like people include relational diagrams with database query questions all the time.  Kind of like "I'm trying to do this" and "this is what I have so far to get there."

Comment: _...maybe design review questions "in pure form" rightfully belong to nowhere, because these have no way to verify research effort... at Programmers design reviews can fly when there's a research effort "embedded", ie if asker did a preliminary investigation of their design and discovered what they believe to be a problem in it. That, I can work with as an answerer / voter..._ (quoted from [Programmers chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=12026035#12026035))

Answer (score 6):

Conceptual software design questions belong on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

But you'll have to ask a better question than "give me your feedback."  Be specific about the particular design issue you are having, and what steps you've taken so far, and you should have no trouble getting good answers there.